# R: Vlookup for a 'for' loop

Tags: r

i'm new to R and trying to use it in place of Excel (where i have more experience). I'm still working out the full 'for' logic, but not having the values to determine if it's working how i think it should is stopping me in my tracks. The goal is to generate what will be used as a factor with 3 levels; 0 = no duplicates, 1 is if duplicate, Oldest, 2 = if duplicate, newest.

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Person <- c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E","E")
Date <- c(1/1/20, 1/1/20,12/25/19, 1/1/20, 1/1/20, 12/25/19, 1/1/20)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
DuplicateStatus <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
IdealResult <- c(0,0,1,2,0,1,2)
mydata <- cbind(Person, Date, ID, DuplicateStatus, IdealResult)
```

I am trying to use a for loop to evaluate if person duplicates. If a person does not duplicate, value= 0 and if they do duplicate, they should have a 1 for the oldest value and a 2 for the newest value (see ideal result). NOTE: I have already sorted the data to be by person and then date, so if duplicated, first appearance is oldest.

previous investigations of Vlookup in R answers here are aimed at merging datasets based on identical values in multiple datasets. Here, i am attempting to modify a column based on the relationship between columns, within a single dataset.

```
currentID = 0
  nextID =0

  for(i in mydata$ID){
    currentID = i 
    nextID = currentID++1
```

### CurrentPerson ##Vlookup function that does - find currentID in ID, return associated value in Person column in same position.

### NextPerson ##Vlookup function that does - find nextID in ID, return associated value in Person column in same position.

if CurrentPerson = NextPerson, then DuplicateStatus at ID associated with current person should be 1, and DuplicateStatus at ID associated with NextPerson = 2.

**This should end when current person = total number of people
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign row number within each group provided if there are more than 1 row in each.

This can be implemented in base R, `dplyr` as well as `data.table`

In base R :

```
mydata$ans <- with(mydata, ave(ID, Person, FUN = function(x) 
                           seq_along(x) * (length(x) > 1)))

#  Person      Date ID IdealResult ans
#1      A 0.0500000  1           0   0
#2      B 0.0500000  2           0   0
#3      C 0.0252632  3           1   1
#4      C 0.0500000  4           2   2
#5      D 0.0500000  5           0   0
#6      E 0.0252632  6           1   1
#7      E 0.0500000  7           2   2
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% group_by(Person) %>% mutate(ans = row_number() * (n() > 1))
```

and with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, ans := seq_along(ID) * (.N > 1), Person]
```

**data**

```
mydata <- data.frame(Person, Date, ID, IdealResult)
```

Comment: Thank you, your dplyr solution works! This also works for another similar dataset I have where persons may duplicate 3+ times.

Answer (score 2):

You really need to spend some time with a simple tutorial on R. Your cbind() function converts all of your data to a character matrix which is probably not what you want. Look at the results of `str(mydata)`. Instead of looping, this creates an index number within each `Person` group and then zeros out the groups with a single observation:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Person, Date, ID, DuplicateStatus, IdealResult)
IR <- ave(mydata$ID, mydata$Person, FUN=seq_along)
IR
# [1] 1 1 1 2 1 1 2
tbl <- table(mydata$Person)
tozero <- mydata$Person %in% names(tbl[tbl == 1])
IR[tozero] <- 0
IR
# [1] 0 0 1 2 0 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I have worked through some tutorials, but often get confused with translating ideas. This data here is merely representative, and i am certain to make errors in generating this data, my apologies. This solution seems to work!

Comment: As a followup, while this solves my problem - is there a way to do a programatic matching? If this were not couched in the context of a logic loop - how would you look up a unique value in one column and return the corresponding value in another column?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand but `which()` takes a logical expression and returns the index values of the rows that meet the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Is what you are looking for just to count the number of observations for a person, in one column (like a column ID)? If so, this will work using `tidyverse`:

```
Person <- c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E","E")
Date <- c(1/1/20, 1/1/20,12/25/19, 1/1/20, 1/1/20, 12/25/19, 1/1/20)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
DuplicateStatus <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
IdealResult <- c(0,0,1,2,0,1,2)
mydata <- data.frame(Person, Date, ID, DuplicateStatus, IdealResult)

library(tidyverse)

mydata <- mydata %>%
    group_by(Person) %>%
    mutate(Duplicate = seq_along(Person))

mydata

# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   Person [5]
  Person   Date    ID DuplicateStatus IdealResult Duplicate
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl>       <dbl>     <int>
1 A      0.05       1               0           0         1
2 B      0.05       2               0           0         1
3 C      0.0253     3               0           1         1
4 C      0.05       4               0           2         2
5 D      0.05       5               0           0         1
6 E      0.0253     6               0           1         1
7 E      0.05       7               0           2         2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. No; I am not trying to count the number of obs per person. I will clarify my post - i guess the question is how to get my DuplicateStatus column to look like my IdealResult column. IF a person is duplicated, I would like to perform a specific set of actions  for that person (in this case, replace values in a column). Ultimately, I need 3 groups for a factor - unique person, or person's 1st or 2nd record.

Comment: What if you took a second step and did this:

mydata %>% group_by(Person) %>% mutate(IdealResults2 = ifelse(max(Duplicate) == 1, 0, Duplicate))

Answer (score -1):

I would argue that n() is the ideal function for you problem

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- mydata %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  mutate(Duplicate = n())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this is similarly close, but seems to assign group to either 1 or 2, rather than 0, 1, or 2.